# add/remove class on >li> click in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have html like

```
 <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>tree</li>
 </ul>
```

now on `ng-click` of every 'li' element I want to add class `active` and remove from other 'li' elements. Also, if the same 'li' is clicked again then I want to remove class 'active'

Comment: From what does the list is created? is it static? is it created using `ngRepeat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your html like

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-click='makeActive("one")' ng-class="{ 'active': active=='one'}">One</li>
    <li ng-click='makeActive("two")' ng-class="{ 'active': active=='two'}">Two</li>
    <li ng-click='makeActive("three")' ng-class="{ 'active': active=='three'}">Three</li>
  </ul>
```

and add new function

```
$scope.makeActive = function(item) {
   $scope.active = $scope.active == item?'':item;
}
```

chekout the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebinmanuval/Lvt5hmL1/)